# Focus to the EditText doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I'm using broadcast receiver to show a dialog.So the flow of code is something like:

**Step1** Getting the requestCode value

**Step2** Based on this requestCode the broadCast receiver goes to if or else if or else part

**Step3** If the value that i entered using some scanner into the EditText(i.e Scan) doesn't matches it shows a Toast "Item Not Available".

**Step 4** Once "Item Not Available" toast comes I need the focus to be on EditText(i.e Scan) so that next time also i can put fresh value in that after clearing it.

So my question is "How can i give focus to the EditText" and set it to the EditText(i.e Scan).

For Reference I'm attaching the snap with code snippet and the layout.xml.Please have a look and drop your suggestions why the focus is going to the listview.

[image]

.java snippet

```
 final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent != null) {
loc = mspinner.getItemAtPosition(mspinner.getSelectedItemPosition())
                        .toString();

                final String ItemNo;
                final String Desc;
                final String StockUnit;

                final String PickSeq;

                final String qtyCount;
                final String qtyonHand;
                final Button mok;
                final Button mcancel;
                final Button mplus;
                final Button mminus;
                final EditText medtQtyCount;
                final EditText medtItem;
                final EditText medtdesc;
                final EditText medtuom;
                final DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
                final String[] UOM = null;
                int requestCode;

                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(InventoryCount.this);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.quantityupdate, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        InventoryCount.this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                //requestCode=Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("idx"));
                requestCode=intent.getIntExtra("idx", -1);
                // create alert dialog
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(InventoryCount.this);
                medtuom = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.edt_mseshipuom_mic);
                mok = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mseshipOk_mic);
                mcancel = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mseshipCancel_mic);
                mplus = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mseshipIncr_mic);
                mminus = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.btn_mseshipDecr_mic);
                medtQtyCount = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.edt_shipShiped_mic);
                medtdesc = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.edt_mseshipQtyOrd_mic);
                medtItem = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.edt_mseshipItemNo_mic);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
    }
    else if (requestCode == 0) {
                    // ItemNo
                    /*if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        Log.i("Scan resul format: ",
                                intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
*/
                        String itNo = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

                        dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
                        MIC_Inventory mic_inventory = dbhelper.getMicInventoryDetails(
                                loc, itNo);
                        dbhelper.closeDatabase();

                        if (mic_inventory != null) {

                            loc = mspinner.getItemAtPosition(
                                    mspinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();

                            ItemNo = mic_inventory.getItemno();
                            Desc = mic_inventory.getItemdescription();
                            PickSeq = mic_inventory.getPickingseq();
                            StockUnit = mic_inventory.getStockunit();
                            qtyonHand = mic_inventory.getQoh();// This value gives
                                                                // QOHand
                            qtyCount = mic_inventory.getQc();

                            medtItem.setText(ItemNo);
                            medtdesc.setText(Desc);
                            medtQtyCount.setText(qtyCount);
                            medtuom.setText(StockUnit);

                            mplus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    String a = medtQtyCount.getText().toString();
                                    int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                                    b = b + 1;
                                    a = a.valueOf(b);
                                    medtQtyCount.setText(a);
                                }
                            });
                            mminus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    int c = Integer.parseInt(medtQtyCount.getText()
                                            .toString());
                                    c = c - 1;
                                    medtQtyCount.setText(new Integer(c).toString());
                                }
                            });
                            mok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    /*
                                     * UOM[mspinnerUom.getSelectedItemPosition()] =
                                     * medtQtyCount .getText().toString();
                                     */
                                    MIC_UOMInternal mic_uom = new MIC_UOMInternal();
                                    mic_uom.setLocation(loc);
                                    mic_uom.setItemno(ItemNo);
                                    String updatedqtyCount = medtQtyCount.getText()
                                            .toString();

                                    if (!qtyCount.equals(updatedqtyCount)) {
                                        mic_uom.setQc(Double
                                                .parseDouble(updatedqtyCount));
                                        mic_uom.setUom(StockUnit);

                                        MIC_Inventory mic_Inventory = new MIC_Inventory();
                                        mic_Inventory.setItemdescription(Desc);
                                        mic_Inventory.setItemno(ItemNo);
                                        mic_Inventory.setLocation(loc);
                                        mic_Inventory.setPickingseq(PickSeq);
                                        mic_Inventory.setQc(updatedqtyCount);
                                        mic_Inventory.setQoh(qtyonHand);
                                        mic_Inventory.setStockunit(StockUnit);

                                        dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
                                        String result = dbHandler
                                                .insertIntoInternal(mic_uom);
                                        if (result.equals("success")) {
                                            result = dbHandler.updateMIC(mic_Inventory);
                                        }
                                        dbHandler.closeDatabase();
                                    }
                                    Intent i = new Intent(InventoryCount.this,
                                            InventoryCount.class);
                                    i.putExtra("et", 1);
                                    i.putExtra("LOCATION", loc);
                                    // i.putExtra("ID", ID);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    // InventoryCount.this.finish();

                                }
                            });
                            mcancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    alertDialog.cancel();

                                }
                            });

                            // show it
                            alertDialog.show();

                        } else {
                            /*
                             * Toast.makeText(this, "Item not available",
                             * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             */


                            toastText.setText("Item not available");
                            Toast toast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 410);
                            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setView(toastLayout);
                            toast.show();




lstView.setFocusable(false);

                        msearchtext.requestFocus();
                        /*InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(msearchtext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);*/
                        msearchtext.setText("");

                        }
    else if (requestCode == 2) {
    }
    else
                {
                    toastText.setText("Problem in Scanning");
                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 410);
                    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setView(toastLayout);
                    toast.show();
                }
}
```

Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_green"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_InvTitle"
        style="@style/pageTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/invTitle" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/txt_InvView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_InvTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#2E9AFE" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invLocation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_InvView"
         android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLoc"
            style="@style/textRegular"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="@string/location" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sploc"
            style="@style/SpinnerItemAppTheme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:editable="false" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invScanType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/invLocation"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_Search_mic"
            style="@style/EditTextAppTheme_Scan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:gravity="center"            
            android:hint="@string/scan" />


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioScanBasedOn_mic"
            style="@style/RadioButtonAppTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioInum_mic"
                style="@style/textRegular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                 android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
                android:checked="true"
                  android:drawablePadding="50dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="@string/itemno" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioNum_mic"
                style="@style/textRegular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                  android:drawablePadding="50dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="@string/manfno" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioUpc_mic"
                style="@style/textRegular"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:button="@drawable/radiobutton_selector"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                  android:drawablePadding="50dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                android:text="@string/upc" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_full_mic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/invScanType" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lay_fullTitle_mic"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/itemno"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/description"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/pick_seq"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/qoh"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/qc"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/textRegular_list"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/uom"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lst_msefull_mic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                style="@style/ListViewAppTheme.White" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_PO_mic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_OrderLstImport_mic"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_OrderLstExport_mic"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_OrderLstExit_mic"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try to call requestFocus() on edt_Search_mic this field?

Comment: yes i do msearchtext.requestFocus() in the else if statement where msearchtext is the edt_Search_mic

Comment: I'm nor really sure about this but you could try: listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);

Comment: I tried it but no luck @DavidRauca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
lstView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        msearchtext.requestFocus();     
    }
});
```

Comment: Sometime focus lost from the Edittext if continuous values goes to the Scan EditText after implementing the above code.